# Tensortrade cannot plot TradingChart

Tags: python, plot

I use Tensortrade in Spyder. I want to plot lie this PlotlyTradingChart().

```
renderer_feed = DataFeed([
    Stream.source(list(data.index)).rename("date"),
    Stream.source(list(data["Open"]), dtype="float").rename("open"),
    Stream.source(list(data["High"]), dtype="float").rename("high"),
    Stream.source(list(data["Low"]), dtype="float").rename("low"),
    Stream.source(list(data["Close"]), dtype="float").rename("close"),
    Stream.source(list(data["Adj Close"]), dtype="float").rename("adj close"),
    Stream.source(list(data["Volume"]), dtype="float").rename("volume")
])

env = default.create(
    portfolio=portfolio,
    action_scheme=SimpleOrders(trade_sizes=1), 
    reward_scheme="risk-adjusted",
    feed=feed,
    renderer_feed=renderer_feed,
    renderer=default.renderers.PlotlyTradingChart(),
    window_size=20,
    min_period=50
)

agent = DQNAgent(env)
agent.train(n_steps=100,n_episodes=1)

env.render()
```

It show error like this.

```
  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basewidget.py:741 in _ipython_display_
    widgets.DOMWidget._ipython_display_(self)

AttributeError: type object 'DOMWidget' has no attribute '_ipython_display_'
```

How to fix it?